# Handle Multiple entries in Fact table in Data Cube

Tags: sql

We have been constructing data cube for our project in which we are facing a problem like 1 to many relationship in the dimension tables and making entries in fact table (duplication).

```
EmployeePersonalInfo Table:                                                    

EmployeePersonalID  Name
E1                  Steve(row1)
E2                  Mark(row2)


EmployeeDiscipline IncidentInfo Table:                                      

EmployeePersonalID  EmployeeDisciplineIncidentID
E1                  Dis1(row1)
E2                  Dis5(row2)


EmployeeDepartmentInfo Table:

EmployeeDepInfoID   EmployeePersonalID
Dep1                E1(row1)
Dep2                E1(row2)
Dep3                E1(row3)
Dep1                E2(row4)
Dep2                E2(row5)
Dep3                E2(row6)
```

While creating a Fact table with the above entries comes as,

```
FactDiscipline Table:

EmployeePersonalD   EmployeeDepInfoID   EmployeeDisciplineIncidentID
E1                  Dep1                Dis1(row1)
E1                  Dep2                Dis1(row2)
E1                  Dep3                Dis1(row3)
E2                  Dep1                Dis5(row4)
E2                  Dep2                Dis5(row5)
E2                  Dep3                Dis5(row6)
```

Actually Employee E1 in associated with discipline incident Dis1. Since EmployeeDisciplineInfo is joined with it , 3 entries will be there for the same Employee E1.  But Employee E1 involved with only one Incident Dis1. In Fact table, it measures the incident count as 3 for Employee E1.

Your help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can i get some suggestions.

Comment: Uh, whats the question?

Comment: Actually EmployeePersonalid was related to one EmployeeDisciplineIncidentId (i.e) E1(employeeId) has one discpline(Dis1) but in the cube it shows 3 as count for EmployeeDisciplineIncidentId but actually E1 was invloved in only one Dis1 . Our expected result was also one as that was the correct data.

Comment: Can i get some suggestions what went wrong here.

Comment: We have no idea what is being asked... So we can't help. See [help/ask] for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted the same question in msdn forum. Those who came across with same problem please look into the below link which may help you.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4e39284f-341c-494d-96a2-74b700e6314c/handle-multiple-entries-in-fact-table-in-data-cube?forum=sqlanalysisservices#4e39284f-341c-494d-96a2-74b700e6314c